# VBA, Excel ODBC driver - Type Mismatch error while using sql query with parameter from cell

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I have problem with `Type Mismatch error` while I do a select with getting parameter from excels cell. I am using excel like a database. 
My code is:

```
Sub maxlg()

    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

    Conn.Open sconnect
        sSQLSting = "SELECT SUM(Sicherkoef*LG/KFM/'" & Range("U17") & "') AS MAXLG From [DATABASE$] WHERE Platzierung =('" & Range("S11") & "') AND RPJ = ('" & Range("U12") & "') "        
        mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
            '=>Load the Data into an array
            'ReturnArray = mrs.GetRows
                    ''OR''
            '=>Paste the data into a sheet
            ActiveSheet.Range("V12").CopyFromRecordset mrs
            'Close Recordset
        mrs.Close


    Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Problem is in getting parameter from here: `RPJ = ('" & Range("U12") & "') "` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have suffered from a little too much copy and paste. It seems that you are wrapping the `Range("U17") value in ticks while using it within a mathematical calculation.

```
sSQLSting = "SELECT SUM(Sicherkoef*LG/KFM/" & Range("U17").value & ") AS MAXLG From [DATABASE$] WHERE Platzierung ='" & Range("S11").value & "' AND RPJ = '" & Range("U12").value & "';"
```

I've also removed some bracketing in the actual text WHERE conditions. They are really only necessary when multiple text values are used with,

```
 ... WHERE [fld1] IN ('abc', 'def')
```

Comment: thanx for quick reply. I have no problem with mathematical calculation it works well. But if i add a clausule where ....RPJ = ('" & Range("U12") & "') " ODBC excel give me an error: Type mismatch error...

Comment: @KarolSvatý - What do you get in the *Immediate* window (`Ctrl+G`) if you add `Debug.print sSQLSting` directly under the string construction? Another point may be that Range("U12") is NULL so that clause would have to address the possibility with `ISNULL(...)` or `RPJ LIKE '" & Range("U12").value & "';" `.